# Difference between cells with DateTime formatting

Tags: excel, date, time

I have 2 cells that are formatted in m/dd/yy hh:mm, is there a way to show the difference in hours between the 2?

Comment: subtract one from the other and format the result `[hh]`

Comment: or, subtract one from the other and multiply by 24

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in Cell `A1` and `A2`, the second being the later Date/Time.

`=(A2-A1)*24` but make sure the format is a number format such as General or Comma (not a date format). Keep in mind that 15 minutes will show as .25 since it is a quarter of an hour.